# Can I get datas from all images in a folder Python Tesseract?

Tags: python, image, path, tesseract, python-tesseract

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'D:\examplepdf2image.png'))
```

I don't want to get just 1 image, I want to get images in a folder, if possible I want to get images one by one, rapidly (like 1 sec cooldown, total 100 images)

*[another my evil idea is waiting for photos live, when a photo comes to folder, program will read it and type it, important thing is live watching but it's not necessarily tho]*

can someone help me?

Thanks...

{https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-text-from-images-with-python-db9b87fe432b}

EDIT:

## extract text from all the images in a folder

```
# storing the text in a single file 
from PIL import Image 
import pytesseract as pt 
import os  

def main(): 
    # path for the folder for getting the raw images 
    path ="C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Masaüstü\\Test\\Input"
  
    # link to the file in which output needs to be kept 
    fullTempPath ="C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Masaüstü\\Test\\Output\\outputFile.txt"
  
    # iterating the images inside the folder 
    for imageName in os.listdir(path): 
        inputPath = os.path.join(path, imageName) 
        img = Image.open(inputPath) 

        # applying ocr using pytesseract for python 
        text = pt.image_to_string(img, lang ="eng") 
  
        # saving the  text for appending it to the output.txt file 
        # a + parameter used for creating the file if not present 
        # and if present then append the text content 
        file1 = open(fullTempPath, "a+") 
  
        # providing the name of the image 
        file1.write(imageName+"\n") 
  
        # providing the content in the image 
        file1.write(text+"\n") 
        file1.close()  
  
    # for printing the output file 
    file2 = open(fullTempPath, 'r') 
    print(file2.read()) 
    file2.close()         

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

I found this code and it is reading and creating text file and writing data here.

Answer (score 0):

For easy scan and get all files from a folder, you can use `glob` or `os.walk`

```py
import glob,os
folder = "your/folder/path"

# to get all *.png files directly under your folder:
files = glob.glob(folder+"/*.png")
# files will be a list that contains all *.png files directly under folder, not include subfolder. 

# or use os.walk:
result = []
for root,_,file in os.walk(folder):
    if file.endswith('.png'):
        result.append(os.path.join(root,file))
# result will be a list that contains all *.png files in your folder, including subfolders.
```

If you want to do live monitor of a folder and trigger something when a new `.png` file is written to the folder,

If you don't need instant response to file creation and the folder is not too crowded,

The simplest thing you can do is keep scanning the same folder every few seconds and compare the new file list to the old file list and handle the new files.

If you want an `eventListener` type of response, where once a file is created, the action is immediately triggered, You can check the python library called `watchdog`.

Here is the PyPI homepage: [watchdog package home page](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/)

With `watchdog` you can create a file monitor like this:

```py
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

class PNG_Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler)
    def __init__(self, ):
        super().__init__(patterns=["*.png", ], ignore_directories=False,)

    def on_created(self, event):
        newfilepath = event.src_path 
        # newfilepath is the path to newly created .png file 
        # you can implement your handler method here.
        # the other methods have the same principle.
        
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        pass

    def on_modified(self, event):
        pass

    def on_moved(self, event):
        pass

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(PNG_Handler(),"path/to/folder", recursive=True)
```

Whenever a '*.png' file is created, the `on_created` function will be called.